# How to Get Target Controller and Action name in myRequestLogger middleware in sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want requested routes controller and action name in sails http.js myRequestLogger custom middleware.

Answer (score 3):

Try `req.options.controller` and `req.options.action`

Answer (score 2):

A middleware similar to below one can log Controller/action, middleware must be before `router` and log prints on `end` event of request.

Controller/action is printed only, **if** one is defined, in case of static file, 404 etc, it may not be defined.

```
middleware: {

  order: [
    ...
    'logController',
    'router',
    ...
  ],

  logController: function(req, res, next) {
    req.on("end", function() {
      sails.log.info('logController##Options2:', req.options); // This contains controller/action along with other data
    });
    sails.log.info('logController##Options1:', req.options); // undefined
    next();
  },
}
```

Logs:

```
RequestLogger##Options1: undefined
...
RequestLogger##Options2: { detectedVerb: { verb: '', original: '/', path: '/' },
  skipRegex: [],
  _middlewareType: 'CORS HOOK: sendHeaders',
  controller: 'user',
  action: 'list',
  locals: { layout: 'layout' } }
```

Remember, a request can match to multiple routes e.g.

```
'/user/list': 'UserController.list',
'user/:id': 'UserController.detail',
```

And a controller can call its third argument `next` to move to next matching controller/action.